# Do I really need to implement Dispose(Boolean)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am working on a bunch of classes in some pretty old code. Many implement the `IDisposable` interface and the `Dispose()` method. But from what [I have read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), any class implementing `IDisposable` should always also implement `Dispose(Boolean)`.

Even the code generated by Visual Basic to help implement `IDisposable` suggest this (sorry about the VB..):

```vb
#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private mDisposed As Boolean

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not mDisposed Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        mDisposed = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        ' TODO: uncomment the following line if Finalize() is overridden above.
        ' GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region
```

It comes with a `Dispose(Boolean)` and a `Dispose()` method, while the `Finalize()` method is commented, suggesting it is the only thing that is optional.

What I find confusing however is, if I **don't** implement the `Finalize()` method, the `Dispose(Boolean)` method seemingly becomes obsolete, as it will literally always be called with `disposing == true`. From my understanding this would result in the exact same execution logic, apart from the method added on top of the stack.

Am I missing something or can I safely ditch `Dispose(Boolean)`?

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the web that details why you should adhere to the standard dispose pattern. Have you read any of those? What exactly is your question here? What people mean/think or a concrete answer about whether you need to implement that method? The latter will not be possible to answer unless you also tell us how you're dealing with inheritance in your project. If you make your class sealed, then no, you don't need to implement it if you don't have a destructor.

Comment: Your missing that you could have subclasses which could have unmanaged resources and thus need `Dispose(false)` and maybe a finalizer.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I did quite a bit of research and all I could find are instructions on when to do it which way. Nothing I found explained the reasons as to why I need to implement that method. My question is exactly as it is stated in the last sentence: "can I safely ditch `Dispose(Boolean)`?" The methods are not sealed. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Freggar this is exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks a lot. If you create a short answer from that comment I will gladly accept it.

Comment: The only thing nice to say about this auto-generated code is that it is never wrong.  But sure, after a while you start to notice how often it seems entirely unnecessary.  This pattern dates back to .NET 1.0, back when it was still pretty common to interop with native code and the SafeHandle classes did not yet exist.  So programmers had a reason to add a finalizer.  Went the way of the dodo at 2.0.  Its only remaining use is being forced to use it when the base class implements it.  Several .NET classes do, like Stream.  This is not common.

Comment: But the sad thing is that style guides and analysis tools still demand it, even though there's no longer a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you can indeed skip the parameter, since you don't have any 'real' disposing to do. Though, imagine that your class was 'Domain Controller + Active Directory + Webserver + Scheduler' all wrapped into a single horrid god-class. You're class might get the woodpecker treatment of being told to dispose over and over again, without the parameter, you don't have any way of tracking 'Im already disposing and can ignore this extra dispose request'

Hans Passant's comment sums the situation quite nicely. A lot of what you are seeing is legacy and may not be needed anymore, but '20mins ago' it was necessary and automation is a blessing.